# Query with inner select and Group by

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I am struggling with this query, here is the table set up:

```
date       | time | count
----------------------------
12/12/2015 | 0:00 | 8
12/12/2015 | 1:00 | 19
12/12/2015 | 2:00 | 36
12/13/2015 | 0:00 | 12
12/13/2015 | 1:00 | 22
12/13/2015 | 2:00 | 30
12/14/2015 | 0:00 | 14
12/14/2015 | 1:00 | 26
12/14/2015 | 2:00 | 38
```

What I would like my query to return is something like this:

```
date       | time | count | DAY       | AVG/HR | AVG/DAY 
---------------------------------------------------------
12/12/2015 | 0:00 | 8     | MONDAY    | 11.33  | 63
12/12/2015 | 1:00 | 19    | MONDAY    | 22.33  | 63
12/12/2015 | 2:00 | 36    | MONDAY    | 34.67  | 63
12/13/2015 | 0:00 | 12    | TUESDAY   | 11.33  | 64
12/13/2015 | 1:00 | 22    | TUESDAY   | 22.33  | 64
12/13/2015 | 2:00 | 30    | TUESDAY   | 34.67  | 64
12/14/2015 | 0:00 | 14    | WEDNESDAY | 11.33  | 78
12/14/2015 | 1:00 | 26    | WEDNESDAY | 22.33  | 78
12/14/2015 | 2:00 | 38    | WEDNESDAY | 34.67  | 78
```

So basically that is returning all rows (there will be months worth of data in the table, with each day having 24 records/hours).  And adding a day of the week field, and an Average of the count per hour along with a average of the count per day of the week.  The last 2 are what I am struggling with.  Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT DATE, TIME, COUNT,
     TO_CHAR(DATE, 'DAY'),
     (SELECT AVG(t2.COUNT) 
        FROM tableXX t2
       WHERE t2.time = t1.time
    GROUP BY t2.time) AS AvgPerHr
     (SELECT AVG(t2.COUNT) 
        FROM tableXX t2
       WHERE TO_CHAR(t2.DATE, 'DAY') = TO_CHAR(t1.DATE, 'DAY')
    GROUP BY TO_CHAR(t2.DATE, 'DAY')) AS AvgPerDay
FROM tableXX t1
ORDER BY DATE, TO_DATE(TIME, 'hh24:mi') ASC;
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated, the query above returns data, but it definitely isn't accurate.

Comment: I don't get the logic of AVG/HR & AVG/DAY. Could you provide detail of these logic?

Comment: @ThitLwinOo So the table has 24 records (each hour in the day) for each date.  I was hoping to get the average for each hour.  So I want to see what the overall average is for the hour of 1 am (01:00).  As for the avg/day, that would just be the average per day of the week.  So what was our average count for a Monday.  I understand this is kind of confusing, I tried to explain it in the mock up of the results table I have above, but it's difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT "DATE", "TIME", "COUNT", TO_CHAR(DATE, 'DAY') "DAY,
       avg( "COUNT" ) Over (partition by  "TIME" ) "AVG/HR",
       SUM( "COUNT" ) Over (partition by  "DATE" )  "AVG/DAY"
FROM tablexx
ORDER BY 1;
```

I use `SUM( "COUNT" )` instead of `AVG( "COUNT" )`, since 63 in the first row of your example appears to be sum per day, not an average.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Sorry, I kind of screwed that up, yes it is the sum of the whole day, but it would be the average of that sum.  So, say you are following along with the results I have above and next monday hits, it should have the same data in the AVG/DAY field that every other monday has ... their daily sums would just be averaged together. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved by using analytical functions.

```
SELECT DATE, TIME, COUNT,
    TO_CHAR(DATE, 'DAY'),
    AVG(t1.COUNT) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY TIME) AS AvgPerHr,
    AVG(t1.COUNT) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY TO_CHAR(DATE, 'DAY'))  AS AvgPerDay
FROM tableXX t1
ORDER BY DATE, TO_DATE(TIME, 'hh24:mi') ASC;
```